# CSS Scaling a div but want html to remain at normal scale

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have an HTML and CSS as follows:

```
<div class="box" style="transform: scale(2);">
    <div class="text">This is my text.</div>
</div>
```

How do I keep the text from scaling when the outer box does via animation?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan or transform the textual element itself!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On theory you can't. The `scale` will work on the entire element and inner child tree. But you can make it look like it's scaling up. Something like that (this method is lighter on the GPU and browser drawing):

```
<div class="box" style="position: relative">
   <div class="box-block" style="position: absolute; transform: scale(2);"></div>
   <div class="text">This is my text.</div>
</div>
```

So the idea is:

1. You have a container element
2. You have two inner holding blocks
3. You animate the one, that looks like the box and scale it.
4. Text `div` will never be touched by the animation, because it's in a separate element.

The structure could be improved, hope that gives you an idea.
Cheers!

Comment: In theory *you can*. by inverting the scaling `0.5` for the child element.

Comment: Probablly wrong expression on my end. The thing is - it's not the best way of doing it the way the guy asked. It will use too much drawing for a simple scaling with inverting the scaling of the inner child, and look blury. No need if it's for a button, probablly on hover.

Answer (score 3):

you need to scale the inner div by 1 divided by original scale (in your case 1 divided by 2 is 0.5):

```html
<div class="box" style="transform: scale(2);">
    <div class="text" style="transform: scale(0.5);">This is my text.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: does this work if I am animating it? I am using jquery animate to scale

Comment: not too sure, depends on what the animation is doing

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure if this is what you want but…

```
.parent {
    transform: scale(2);
}
.child {
    transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

Will scale child down. For scale `x` you have to use scale `1/x` for all children.

Comment: having it inline with jquery animate scales it up to 2x and back down to 0.5x so the text is grainy

Comment: I don’t know what jQuery is using for scaling, probably `transform`, but the thing with this property is it can look not very pretty. Even simple `transform: translate()` used on `<canvas>` can blur the image, so I would expect it can affect the text itself. Depending of course on browser and other factors (graphic card?).

Answer (score 2):

All the content of the transformed element is transformed with it, just like when using opacity, you need to set the text outside the scaling container, and using some positioning on them to make the overlay one another:

```
<div class="text">This is my text.</div>
<div class="box" style="transform: scale(2);"></div>
```

Alternatively, you can try to avoid the transform by setting an opposite style to the contained element:

```
<div class="box" style="transform: scale(2);">
     <div class="text" style="transform: scale(0.5);">This is my text.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`transform: scale(x)` scales the *entire* element with all of it's childs. I cannot see your CSS, but you should implement a hard-coded solution to make sure all your text isn't being scaled, in this case, it would be:

```
.box:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
}

.box:hover > .text {
    transform: scale(0.5); // change it back to half of the intended size by the .box;
}
```